# How can i use different date filer count in mongo db aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to filter data according to type and then date wise

Desired output
[image: Out Put]

```
[
  {
    "_id": "WA",
    "dec": 1,
    "jan": 3,
    "nov": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "CA",
    "dec": 1,
    "jan": 2,
    "nov": 3
  }
]
```

count number are only for example

Query:-

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$state",
    countState: {
      $count: {}
    },
    count2State: {
      $count: {}
    },
     count3State: {
      $count: {}
    }
  }
})
```

Please checkout mongo playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0H8SvLaJkX4) for easy understanding

Comment: Please provide expected result which matches the input data and proved result as text rather than screenshot.

Comment: Please add your playground data here in the question, as well the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Could be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { state: "$state", month: { $month: "$orderDate" } },
         count: { $count: {} }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$_id.state",
         counts: { $push: { count: "$count", month: "$_id.month" } }
      }
   }
])
```

Or [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) could be an option

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/utQCSayXWvN)

Comment: yes this will work, just need to order by month